# what's rendering frame in javascript's optimization context

Tags: javascript

I'm reading [this article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/optimize-javascript-execution?hl=en) about `javascript` optimization and there is the following passage there:

> When visual changes are happening on screen you want to do your work
>   at the right time for the browser, which is right at the start of the
>   frame. The only way to guarantee that your JavaScript will run at the
>   start of a frame is to use requestAnimationFrame.

And this:

> Frameworks or samples may use setTimeout or setInterval to do visual
>   changes like animations, but the problem with this is that the
>   callback will run at some point in the frame, possibly right at the
>   end, and that can often have the effect of causing us to miss a frame,
>   resulting in jank.

I'm wondering what is frame here? Is it referred to a picture that browser or device puts up at the 60 fps interval? If so, how can `callback run at some point in the frame` as stated in the passage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a frame in this context is the update cycle of the screen.

The screen is not updated all at once, instead it is updated from the top to the bottom during the update cycle. In a CRT monitor it was an actual beam sweaping across the screen that lit up the phosphor, in an LCD screen it's just pixels that get updated with new data but it's sweaping in the same manner.

If screen updates are synchronised with the frame rate, animations will flow smoothly, but if an interval runs at a different rate it will do double updates or no updates for some cycles which is visible as jerky movement. If the update happens right when the sweap passes that part of the screen, you can even see [tearing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_tearing).

The ideal time to update animations is during the [vertical blanking interval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_blanking_interval). That's when the sweep has finished one update cycle and is waiting for the next to start. That's what `requestAnimationFrame` is for.

Comment: thanks, I need some time to process it in my head :). I'll get back soon with questions

Comment: _If screen updates are synchronised with the frame rate_ - I assume that by `frame rate` here you're referring to a browser `repaint cycle rate`? It seems that there are two frames: - the first one is produced by a device to refresh the screen, the second is produced by a browser and is often referred to as `repaint`, correct?

Comment: @Maximus: The frame rate is the update cycle of the screen, that's the only one that is relevant. If the browser does some sort of double buffering, you won't notice it, because it would be synchronised with the screen frame rate. The repaint is when the browser updates the screen according to changes in the DOM, and that happens when no JavaScript is running. Using `requestAnimationFrame` allows you to make changes to the DOM so that the repaint for those changes (which happens as soon as your script returns) is synchronised with the screen frame rate.

Comment: Thanks, so what you're saying is that browser can start making repaint as soon as JavaScript's execution is ended and that repaint can occur in the middle of the update cycle of the screen? But if I use `requestAnimationFrame ` the browser waits until update cycle of the screen is finished (beginning of the vertical blanking interval), then executes javascript, makes repaint and this new picture of DOM after repaint is picked up by the next screen update cycle?

Comment: Thanks, now I understand it. One more question, given I use `requestAnimationFrame`, what happens if JavaScript fails to finish executing during vertical blinking interval, but finishes during screen update cycle, does browser wait for another vertical blinking interval or nevertheless makes repaint during the update screen cycle?

Comment: @Maximus: The repaint isn't done differently because the changes were made from code triggered by `requestAnimatinFrame`, so the repaint is done as soon as the function finishes.

Comment: So if JS executes longer than vertical blinking interval, it's actually a disadvantage to use `requestAnimationFrame`? If didn't use it and code would execute longer than vertical blinking interval, would repaint be done differently (maybe wait for another blinking interval)?

Comment: @Maximus: You still have the advantage of having the code start synchronised with the screen rate. Unless the execution time varies a lot, it will still prevent jerkiness. The repaint doesn't wait for blanking intervals in either case.

Comment: Right, got you, thanks a lot! Maybe you could update your answer a bit with what I've discovered based on your comments so that other people get the complete picture.